# Swipe Tab in android showing bad picture after swipe

Tags: android, fragment

I implemented a swipe bar to my app, now when I add 3 images to each bar and return to the first one it seems the image changed to the third one, here is where I complete my tabs;

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        switch (container.getChildCount()) {
            case 0: {
                TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView.setText("GIOTONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN ");
                ImageView imag1 = (ImageView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);

                new ImageLoadTask("http://gioton.com/bar/DAC.jpg", imag1).execute();

                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView2.setText("prueba color 2 verde");
                ImageView imag2 = (ImageView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                imag2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
                }
            case 2: {
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView3.setText("Azulcito");
                ImageView imag3 = (ImageView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                imag3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
                    }

        }

        return rootView;

    }
```

My main code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Gioton";
            case 1:
                return "prueba 2";
            case 2:
                return "Prueba 3 Az 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        switch (container.getChildCount()) {
            case 0: {
                TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView.setText("GIOTONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN ");
                ImageView imag1 = (ImageView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);

                new ImageLoadTask("http://gioton.com/bar/DAC.jpg", imag1).execute();

                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                TextView textView2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView2.setText("prueba color 2 verde");
                ImageView imag2 = (ImageView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                imag2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;
                }
            case 2: {
                TextView textView3 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView3.setText("Azulcito");
                ImageView imag3 = (ImageView)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                imag3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                break;
                    }

        }

        return rootView;

    }
  }
}
```

and my fragment layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold|normal|italic" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you changed tab? are you sure that the rest is working as well?

Comment: @Virthuss It changes tabs good but when i return to the first one it show the content of the third one , idk what is happening

Comment: Do you mean that then content doesnt change?

Comment: @Virthuss we just solved it, thanks anyway